# .htaccess rewrite rule - change url of any requested jpg to go to another server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to setup a rewrite rule in .htaccess for a specific folder and its subfolders so that any request for a jpg image file gets redirected to another domain.  The problem is the path is also getting redirected which I do not want to happen.

Example - I need

http://www.example.com/test/media/0/1/test.jpg to get directed to 
http://www.example1.com/img/gallery/test.jpg

and

http://www.example.com/test/media/5/7/test1.jpg to get directed to 
http://www.example1.com/img/gallery/test1.jpg

I have created a .htaccess file in ../test/media folder and in there I have at the moment

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpg))$ http://www.example1.com/img/gallery/$1
```

the request is being redirected but it gets redirected to

http://www.example1.com/img/gallery/0/1/test.jpg

when I need it to be

http://www.example1.com/img/gallery/test.jpg

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify yor rule this way:

`RewriteRule /([^./]+\.(jpg))$ http://www.example1.com/img/gallery/$1`

And it will take only filename after last slash.

Comment: You are a star - That worked brilliantly. thank you. On a side note. There may be occasions where the file is not present on the redirected server.  Is there anyway I can redirect again but to a different server and location if I get back a 404?

Comment: This should be done on the target location (example1.com), because example.com doesn't communicate with example1.com.